# How to populate a ListBox in a UserForm with a variable set of Rows from Last Row?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Worksheet 'Sheet1', With data ranging from 'A:R', Rows keep adding as new Entry is input. With every entry the range of rows differ, so the the Rows in 'Column A' are repeated, that way it shows up well in a Pivot table. Now to check if the last entry was infact pasted, one way to check is to hit 'Cltr+Down' keys. What I have is a ListBox in a Userform to populate the last entered Entry. But it shows only 1 Row which is the Last Row. How to show if that particular entry has suppose 5 rows?

I have this code which shows the last row entered. I know there's a major chunk missing which defines the range. I just don't know how to do it. Please help.
Here is a Screenshot of the Database from where I need to populate a ListBox in a Userform.

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the Userform with ListBox when I click the "CommandButton1"

[Screenshot of Userform when 'CommandButton1' is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWAhe.jpg)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim lr As Long
Dim x(1 To 2, 1 To 18), y As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
         lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        UserForm1.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 18
        For y = 1 To 18
            x(1, y) = .Cells(1, y)
            x(2, y) = .Cells(lr, y)
        Next y
              UserForm1.ListBox1.List = x
    End With
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

**I want the record of 025 - GRACE PHILLIPS (from the database) to show up on ListBox and later when a new entry is added, it should show the new one entered**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try another approach by using an ADODB.recordset

```
  Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim criteria As String, fldName As String, shtName As String
    Dim con As Object  ' ADODB.Connection
    Dim rcd As Object  ' ADODB.Recordset
    Dim colCount As Long

    ' Assuming the list has a header
    Set con = GetExcelConnection(ThisWorkbook.FullName, True)

    Set rcd = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    'Set rcd = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Assuming the list is on the first sheet and
    shtName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name

    ' Reading the list into a recordset
    With rcd
        .ActiveConnection = con
        .CursorType = 2  ' adOpenDynamic
        .LockType = 3    ' adLockOptimistic
        .Source = "SELECT * FROM [" & shtName & "$]"
        .Open
    End With

    colCount = rcd.Fields.Count + 1
    ' Move to the last record in the list
    rcd.MoveLast

    ' Trying to find the row where S.L.No. does contain avalue
    Do While IsNull(rcd.Fields(0).Value)
        rcd.MovePrevious
        If rcd.BOF Then
            MsgBox "No S.L.No found", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error - Exit"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop

    ' get the value and the fieldname for the filter
    criteria = rcd.Fields(0).Value
    fldName = rcd.Fields(0).Name


    ' Filter the list by the value in the first column and last row
    ' This assumes you do not have different areas with the same value
    rcd.Filter = fldName & " = '" & criteria & "'"

    ' Prpearing everything for the Userform
    Dim frm As New UserForm1
    Load frm
    With frm
        .ListBox1.ColumnCount = colCount
        .ListBox1.Column = rcd.GetRows   ' This transfers the filtered records into the lsitbox
        .Show
    End With

End Sub

Function GetExcelConnection(ByVal Path As String, _
    Optional ByVal Headers As Boolean = True) As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim objConn As Object ' ADODB.Connection
    Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & Path & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=" & _
        IIf(Headers, "Yes", "No") & """"
    objConn.Open strConn
    Set GetExcelConnection = objConn
End Function
```

Comment: `criteria = rcd.Fields(0).Value` This line gives "Invalid use of Null" error.

Comment: From what I understand, there's a code available which has an Input Box and a listbox in a Userform. The ListBox gets populated by what you enter in the Input box. Something like a Google Search Box. Now that code works on a similar procedure, right? It shows only those rows which contain a certain word (in this case the word entered in the TextBox. Now How can we replace the 'TextBox' with the LastRow Cell, which I had posted in my first post. We do get the last row, right? From that How can we populate the listbox with matching cell value.

Comment: I updated the answer. I do not understand your last comment. You never mentioned an Inputbox before. My code does not work like a googe search box. But you are right, I filter the list by the value for S.L.NO which is in the last row and first column of the list. According by your feedback the programm also identifies lines belonging to the list which do not have a value in the column for S.L.NO. I tried to remedy that by adding some code checking that.

Comment: Nevermind the previous comment, I was just trying to explain another example elsewhere... COming back to this.. After you updated this, It works like a CHARM!!!! BEAUTIFUL . Thank you so much. This is what I wanted. I hope this would work when I add new records as well right? I've got to check it. But thanks. Just one last thing, How to display the Header as well? Right now it is only missing the header.

Comment: You can't unless you use the [Rowsource porperty of the listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50110913/6600940) Update: Sorry, I might be wrong. Just give me a minute

Comment: The code you've just provided, does return the last record. I tried pasting new rows with new "SL. No." and it works. It displays the new entry along with the number of row entries as well.

Comment: Good to hear. Regarding the heading: This only seems to be possible if you use the rowsource proprty as I wrote in my previous comment.

Comment: Hey there, I updated my Database with another column added to it. Now there are two columns with only numbers. Earlier - 18 columns, Current - 19 columns. IS this why I am getting an error "Run-time error '3001': Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another." and in the VB editor, the highlighter is stuck at this line `rcd.Filter = fldName & " = '" & criteria & "'"`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that

**Option 1** You could use CurrentRegion to get the range. I am not sure if this works for you.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ListBox1.List = rg.Value
End Sub
```

**Option 2** Or you determine the last row like you did in your posted code and use this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rg = Range("A1:R" & lr)
    ListBox1.List = rg.Value
End SUb
```

Please add the worksheet and userform reference as you need it

**Update**  Based on the comment use for the rg in *Option 2* the following line

```
Set rg = Range("A" & lr & ":R" & lr)
```

**Update 2** I assumed the rows which you would like to add to your listbox are identified by the first column which contains S.L.No.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim rg As Range, rg1 As Range
    Dim lr As Long

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rg = Range("A1" & ":R" & lr)

    rg.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=rg.Cells(lr, 1).Value
    Set rg1 = rg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
   ' Assumption is the newly added rows are in one and therefore in the last area
    Set rg1 = rg1.Areas(rg1.Areas.Count)


    ListBox1.ColumnCount = rg.Columns.Count
    ListBox1.List = rg1.Value

    rg.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: The code you provided does work but it shows the entire range of Database. I just need the last entered Database Entry for instance Record No. 025 with name  GRACE PHILLIP and her respective columns until Column R to show up on the listrow. Please note that GRACE PHILLIP has 3 rows to it's entry. How do I do this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok, then I got you wrong. I updated the answer. Is that what you need?

Comment: Almost.... Just that "GRACE PHILLIP has 3 rows in her record. How do I show 3 records of her? Note that this '3 record' would vary from record to record as I keep entering them. Thank you!

Comment: Ho do you identify the rows which belong to GRACE PHILLIP? By the S.L.NO?

Comment: Yes, by Sl. No.

Comment: Please look at _Update 2_

Comment: Could you add a breakpoint at the line `ListBox1.List = rg1.Value` and when in debug modus select `rg1`, i.e. enter `rg1.select` in the immediate window. What is the result?

Comment: It selects Row 1 of Columns A:R. Although I must say, something weird happened as well, Command Button 3 stopped functioning, and the whole range got replaced with a Table with just the Header. Weird.

Comment: Then the Autofilter did not work. The code sets an autofilter in column 1 (S.L.NO). Criteria is the number from the last row in the first column. If you only get the header row this means the autofilter returns nothing. This is strange. Can you autofilter your list by the last S.L.NO in column 1? What is the result?

Comment: Do you mean changing this `rg.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=rg.Cells(lr, 1).Value` by replacing `lr' with the row no.? I'm not a professional. The codes I've got is from the internet itself so forgive me for the lack of knowledge. Thank you so much for the effort though.

Comment: No, I mean to autofilter manually. And it woiuld also be good if you could also post the value of cell in the first cloumn and last row of your list.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Can I give you the Worksheet? If by filtering you mean 'filter' in a Table Header? IN that case. No, my data is not in an Excel Table. It is just a pasted entry from another workbook through VBA code.

Comment: You do not how to use the autofilter?

Comment: I posted another approach. Maybe this is easier to copy & paste for you as this one.